# expressionengine htaccess masked cp

Tags: regex, .htaccess, expressionengine

I'm using this htaccess for removing index.php on an ExpressionEngine MSM site http://d.pr/n/RZTo

It does what it needs but won't allow me to access the site via a masked CP (which I need for using the Mountee app.

Any ideas why I'd get a 404 when I try to hit the /admin.php for the site?

The secondary MSM site is under a sub-folder of the primary domain.

Comment: Add this to your trailing slash block: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=POST [NC]

See https://gist.github.com/3438705

One guess off the top of my head is, does admin.php have the correct path to the system folder defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got a similar set up to you but in the htaccess for the second site, I don't have a rewritebase rule and have `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [L]` (i.e. no reference to the folder name).

Comment: I've actually reverted to my standard htaccess file on both sites which uses this rule John. We're all good again.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the standard htaccess file I've reverted to https://gist.github.com/4053195